# How do I simultaneously filter the answer section that is associated with the questions?

Tags: javascript, loops, search

I have been able to filter the questions. But how do I also filter the answers associated with each question simultaneously?

This is the HTML

```
<input style="text-align: center" type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="What would you like to know?" title="Type in a name">

</span>
<p class="example"><span>What is a "four season" sunroom?</span> </p>

<p class="answer">A traditional sunroom is usually treated more like an outdoor enclosure than a home addition, because it is designed only for seasonal use during mild weather. In contrast, a four season sunroom is more like adding a new room to your home, by incorporating
  heavily insulated materials to keep it comfortable even during the extremes of winter and summer. A &#8220;true&#8221; four season sunroom should feel like an extension of your home and is easy to keep conditioned and comfortable.</p>

</span>
<p class="example"><span>What is a conservatory</span> </p>

<p class="answer">The terms sunroom and conservatory are often used interchangeably, but there are some informal differences. A conservatory typically has a larger percengtage of glass included in the walls than a sunroom does. Also, a conservatory almost always has a
  glass roof, while most sunrooms have a traditional solid roof. Conservatories are common in Europe.</p>

</span>
<p class="example"><span>What sunroom styles are there</span> </p>

<p class="answer">LivingSpace offers four different types of sunrooms: the Cathedral Sunroom, the Studio Sunroom, the Integrated Sunroom, and the Specialized Sunroom. Further information on them can be found <a href="https://livingspacesunrooms.com/sunrooms/"><b>here</b></a>.
</p>
```

This is the javscript

```
function myFunction() {
  var input, toUpper, ul, question, span, i;
  answer = document.querySelector(".answer");
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  toUpper = input.value.toUpperCase();
  question = document.getElementsByClassName("example");
  for (i = 0; i <   question.length; i++) {
    span = question[i].getElementsByTagName("span")[0];
    if (span.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(toUpper) > -1) {
      question[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      question[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the codepen
https://codepen.io/mfahad24/pen/wxQaPz

Comment: Wrap the question / answer pairs in a container and hide that container.

Comment: If there is only one answer per question like in the example HTML, you can simply do something like `answer[i].style.display = "" / "none"`